# How to easily handle dynamic view height and width using autolayout?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

[image]

I have a view like above in Figure 1, The view 1, 2, 3 are aligned to left to their parent view, and the view 4,5,6 are aligned to right to their parent view. 
And when the parent view's frame changes with higher height and narrower width, I want the subviews layout like Figure 2, which means view 1, 2, 3 are aligned to bottom left, and view 4, 5, 6 are aligned to top left. Is there an easy way to do this using autolayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can handle this issue by adding constraints like in figure 2  and figure 1 separately and enabling/disabling them when the view increases height disable the figure 1 constraints and enable constraints for figure 2.You can easily do that by taking 1 outlet collection for each figure and then enable disable them depending on your requirement

Comment: Hmm, that's a way, but my concern is, will Interface Builder have conflict constraints if I'm doing so?

Comment: No you can disable constraint for one view in IB.There is a check in IB to do that .This  is the only clean solution or you will have to create two views and hide or show depending on the height